# Google Webmaster Central Channel

Tags: seo, google

Since there are so many Google Webmaster Central videos on Youtube which one do you think every Webmaster should see?

http://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleWebmasterHelp

Answer (score 2):

Not an actual answer: I think Google should pay someone to transcribe those videos and make them into actual text files I can read, scan, and friggin search.

Text is always useful, video should be, in this case, for people who really want to see Matt Cutts :)